# Creating Weekly dataframe from Daily dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

trying to get weekly data from dataframe based on Dates column but facing issue is Daily dataframe is multi year dataframe that contains dates from 2016-2022
So the code I tried is working fine but from 31-Dec-2018 it gives wrong result, because it treat as 31-Dec-2018 as separate week but what it should do is it should consider 31 as part of 4 - jan- 2019 week ending. Any idea on how to resolve this.

Daily Dataframe:

| Date | Open | High | Low | Close |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 24-Dec-2018 | 26925 | 26982.6 | 26737.1 | 26810 |
| 26-Dec-2018 | 26700 | 27070 | 26439.6 | 27067.8 |
| 27-Dec-2018 | 27198 | 27260 | 26860 | 26877.6 |
| 28-Dec-2018 | 27155 | 27350 | 27051.05 | 27290 |
| 31-Dec-2018 | 27400 | 27429.5 | 27242.1 | 27318 |
| 01-Jan-2019 | 27300.2 | 27532 | 27135 | 27526 |
| 02-Jan-2019 | 27410.3 | 27523 | 27175.1 | 27275.3 |
| 03-Jan-2019 | 27260 | 27319.4 | 27062.3 | 27076 |
| 04-Jan-2019 | 27169 | 27431 | 27058 | 27376 |
| 07-Jan-2019 | 27555 | 27586.75 | 27375 | 27382.2 |
| 08-Jan-2019 | 27388.4 | 27632.65 | 27292 | 27610.2 |
| 09-Jan-2019 | 27752.2 | 27784.4 | 27451.4 | 27752 |
| 10-Jan-2019 | 27720.3 | 27740 | 27587.1 | 27630.05 |
| 11-Jan-2019 | 27675 | 27689.9 | 27502.55 | 27533 |
| 14-Jan-2019 | 27465 | 27480 | 27300.95 | 27347.6 |
| 15-Jan-2019 | 27410.6 | 27539 | 27392.1 | 27520 |

My code Output:

| Date | weekday | Open | High | Low | Close |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 21-Dec-2018 | Friday | 26988.8 | 27425 | 26888.6 | 26971.8 |
| 28-Dec-2018 | Friday | 26925 | 27350 | 26439.6 | 27290 |
| 31-Dec-2018 | Monday | 27400 | 27429.5 | 27242.1 | 27318 |
| 04-Jan-2019 | Friday | 27300.2 | 27532 | 27058 | 27376 |
| 11-Jan-2019 | Friday | 27555 | 27784.4 | 27292 | 27533 |
| 18-Jan-2019 | Friday | 27465 | 27676 | 27300.95 | 27560 |
| 25-Jan-2019 | Friday | 27560.05 | 27674.95 | 27067 | 27158.95 |

Code I'm using:

```
    temp_df = daily_df.copy()
    temp_df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(temp_df['Date'], format='%d-%b-%Y')
    weekly_data = temp_df.assign(wk=temp_df['Date'].dt.isocalendar().week, ye=temp_df['Date'].dt.year, iso_ye=temp_df['Date'].dt.isocalendar().year).groupby(['wk', 'ye', 'iso_ye'])\
    .aggregate({'Date': ['max'], 'Open': ['first'],'High': ['max'], 'Low': ['min'],
                'Close': ['last']}).reset_index()

# check if maximum date in week is in previous year
weekly_data.loc[weekly_data['Date', 'max'].dt.year != weekly_data['iso_ye'], 'wk'] = 1

weekly_data.columns = weekly_data.columns.droplevel(1)
weekly_data = weekly_data.sort_values(by=['Date']).drop(columns=['ye', 'iso_ye']).reset_index(drop=True)
weekly_data['weekday'] = weekly_data['Date'].dt.day_name()
weekly_data['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(weekly_data['Date'], format='%Y%m%d')
weekly_data['Date'] = weekly_data['Date'].dt.strftime('%d-%b-%Y')
weekly_data.drop(['wk'], axis=1)
weekly_data = weekly_data.reindex(columns=['Date', 'weekday', 'Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close'])
weekly_data
```

Answer (score 1):

Your expected output is not clear. Maybe you can compute the difference between 1970-01-04 (Sunday) and divide the result in days by 7 (true/floor div):

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

origin = pd.to_datetime('1970-01-02')
dates = origin + pd.TimedeltaIndex((df['Date'] - origin).dt.days // 7 * 7 + 7, unit='D')

ohlc = df.assign(Date=dates).groupby('Date', as_index=False).mean()
```

Output:

```
>>> ohlc
        Date          Open          High           Low         Close
0 2018-12-28  26941.000000  27104.200000  26678.900000  26918.466667
1 2019-01-04  27305.100000  27430.780000  27133.110000  27297.060000
2 2019-01-11  27516.980000  27634.960000  27352.700000  27550.090000
3 2019-01-18  27516.866667  27569.633333  27398.533333  27466.866667
```

Details:

```
>>> pd.concat([df['Date'], pd.Series(dates, name='WeekDate')], axis=1)
         Date   WeekDate
0  2018-12-24 2018-12-28
1  2018-12-26 2018-12-28
2  2018-12-27 2018-12-28

3  2018-12-28 2019-01-04
4  2018-12-31 2019-01-04
5  2019-01-01 2019-01-04
6  2019-01-02 2019-01-04
7  2019-01-03 2019-01-04

8  2019-01-04 2019-01-11
9  2019-01-07 2019-01-11
10 2019-01-08 2019-01-11
11 2019-01-09 2019-01-11
12 2019-01-10 2019-01-11

13 2019-01-11 2019-01-18
14 2019-01-14 2019-01-18
15 2019-01-15 2019-01-18
```

Comment: sorry for the confusion, Updated my question with daily dataframe, and my tried code output which gives wrong data from 31st-Dec-2018, because code not considering 31st as part of week ending on 4-jan-2019

Comment: Did you try my code? I updated with your new dataframe. Can you check it. Something wrong?